Is it undefined behavior to alias members using a union?
Is it undefined behavior to alias members like this
struct Vec3 {
     union {int x,r;};
     union {int g,y;};
     union {int b,z;};
};

If I do this
Vec3 v;
v.x = 5;
return v.r; // undefined behavior???

I want standard wording if this is undefined. Don't want to hear that compilers support it as an extension.
Do not suggest other ways to fix this via member accessors function or creating different types answer the question.

i will edit the question a typing mistake happened

In C++ do NOT use (untagged) unions. They are not the simple things they are in C++. You're reading from an inactive union member and that's UB. (undefined is the wrong word).

undefined here means undefined behavior lol what do you mean @PepijnKramer

yea it expresses what I wanted to do crate a vector3 like glm @DrewDormann

"undefined here means undefined behavior"  undefined does not mean the same thing as undefined behavior in the C++ language.

@DrewDormann how so? and also in the question i explicitly said undefined behavior

Also if you have a vector representing a direction AND one representing a color make that TWO distinct types. Don't try to outsmart yourself. C++ is a typesafe language so make use of the typesystem.  Though if you insist abusing the typesytem struct Vect3 {int x; int y; int z; int& r = x; int& g = y; int& b = z;} will make r,g,b aliases of a kind to x,y and z.

@PepijnKramer it costs more space that is not what I wanted at all. I am not out smarting I am just changing the name of the member through a union and asking if it is undefined.

What I mean is that unions in C++ are not nearly as simple as unions where in "C". In fact I consider them UB traps. The C++ core guidelines think so too and state do NOT use untagged unions in C++ use std::variant

What you are doing is considered "Undefined Behavior" by the C++ language.  v.r represents a value that you are reading, but have never initialized.

@PepijnKramer I hate std::variant it ia ugly, and won't fix this problem also the compile times are insane with tuple and variant.  I don't care about C and I know that every compiler on earth treats this as well defined.

Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union and make sure what "active member" means

@PepijnKramer I did read it that is why I am asking this.

Since your union member have a common initial sequence I think it's not ub to do so

@user24551355 I understand your statement about std::variant being "ugly". But I prefer "correct" over ugly any day. And as said I prefer semantically clear correct programs too. So if it is space you're worried about I would still recommend you create two distinct struct types.  Why do you insist on only having on Vec3 type?

@user24551355 The reason std::variant doesn't solve the problem is because union also doesn't solve the problem. This usage of union is Undefined Behaviour in C++. In your example v.x is the active member, you are not allowed to read from v.r.

@GuillaumeRacicot It is read the cppreference page, it clearly states : It is undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written.

This almost fits the exception in [class.mem p25] (using C++20 N4860) which allows punning when the union has two struct members with a common initial sequence.  But, somewhat illogically, not when the two elements are of the same fundamental type.

@GuillaumeRacicot I don't believe non-class types can have a common initial sequence, but I am not certain.

This is devolving into a discussion forum, I believe.  With new questions being asked in the comments.

@NateEldredge yea I got confused by that example

@DrewDormann Haha it does, it also shows (at least to me) again that c++ unions are a minefield.

@FrançoisAndrieux well the other tjing is compile times too, I would rather ise a tagged union with an enum than a std variant even if std variant is more "C++" I hate it with every word it is still ugly, long to compile and bad syntax why would I use it?

I assume the end goal here is to get some "syntactic sugar" so that you can write either v.x or v.r to refer to the same element.  Setting aside whether that's actually good style, you could ask (or search for) a separate question about whether there's a clearly legal way to do it.

@DrewDormann read the edit

@user24551355 Your question has been answered.  Both in the comments and in the duplicate.  You should click [Ask Question] if you have new questions, based on this answer.

@user24551355 That is all pretty subjective, but assuming it is true, you would use it for the same reason you would use other constructs that increase safety at the expense of compile time : to avoid bugs and errors which is generally considered are very worthwhile trade-off.

@FrançoisAndrieux I do use them like unique_ptr the tradeoff is well worth it for memory safety and the sybtax is nit hdious unlike std variant though

You also tagged type punning. C++ core guidelines : C.183: Don’t use a union for type punning

@PepijnKramer I tagge this as type punning to see if it qualifies as such but ik that type punning is ub

I just referenced it for completeness, not all future readers might be aware ;)

@FrançoisAndrieux becuase I want to save header space obviously:kappa:

The only purpose of union is to implement std::variant.

@Jarod42 what you actually don't need a union if you don't want the constexpr support you can use a char buffer of max size of the types
